# Orion Context Broker and Docker - Empty reply from server

Tags: mongodb, docker, fiware, fiware-orion

I recently started project involving Orion Context Broker. Tried to started it on windows using docker.

https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/

First method didn't come out good, error that I got while using original code from tutorial is:

```
   ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
   in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
   expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
   in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 5, column 2
```

Then I decided to move on to second method, I started mongoDB with default parameters. I got it to listening for connections and used the 2A way from docker site.

```
   sudo docker run -d --name orion1 -p 1026:1026 fiware/orion
```

It seems to have started because it has not returned any errors while starting. However if I use:

```
   curl localhost:1026/version
```

I receive no response whatsoever it just freeze and in mongoDB console I don't have any new connection. The addr of docker container is right. Firewall is off. It seems like it haven't connected, but it's running. If I want to start again orion context broker it tells me that it's already running, so then I stop it, remove orion1 and can start it again. When I connect to running mongoDB from another console it shows a new connection while when connecting with Context Broker there isn't.

When I checked CB logs I got

```
time=Tuesday 24 Oct 21:37:32 2017.378Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A 
trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | 
op=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[152]:mongoConnect |
msg=Database Startup Error (cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries  with a 1000 microsecond interval)
```

Comment: The error in docker-compose.yml you are getting is a bit weird... How did you get that file? Copy-pasting from https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/?

Comment: Yes, compose file is copypasted from that site so it seemed uncanny for me that such error will occur. I run it as they wish. As forthe Orion addres there's an edit in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to docker-compose.yml fails, copy paste sometimes is tricky... I'll recommend you [to download directly from github repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml). The following should work:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/master/docker/docker-compose.yml
```

With regards to Orion docker failing to connect the database, have a look to [section 2B in the docker documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/docker/index.html):

```
sudo docker run -d --name orion1 --link mongodb:mongodb -p 1026:1026 fiware/orion -dbhost mongodb
```

It seems you are missing the `--link mongodb:mongodb` parameter (which requires previously run a MongoDB docker named `mongodb`, of course).

Comment: You're right now the orion and mongo start using first method. However I can't connect to it, because _curl : Unable to connect to the remote server_.  Firewall is down and I'm using correct ip and port. Docker now starts withou any errors.

Comment: _curl docAddr:1026/version_ where docAddr is a ipv4 address of orion container running in docker.

Comment: I tried it now and it works. I changet the addr to containter ip, because before the command with localhost returned timeout, but it was before orion started properly. It does now, thank you.